# Spark DataFrame ArrayType or MapType for checking for value in column

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe, and one column is a list of IDs. I want to, for example, get the count of rows which have a certain ID in it.

AFAIK the two column types relevant to me are `ArrayType` and `MapType`. I could use the map type because checking for membership inside a map/dict is more efficient than checking for membership in an array.

However, to use the map I would need to filter with a custom `udf` rather than the built in (scala) function `array_contains`

with a `MapType` I can do :

```
from pyspark.sql.types import BooleanType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

df = spark.createDataFrame([("a-key", {"345": True, "123": True})], ["key", "ids"])

def is_in_map(k, d):
    return k in d.keys()

def map_udf(key):
    return udf(lambda d: is_in_map(key, d), BooleanType())

c = df.filter(map_udf("123")(df.ids)).count()
```

or with an `ArrayType` I can do :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_contains

df = spark.createDataFrame([("a-key", ["345", "123"])], ["key", "ids"])
c = df.filter(array_contains(df.ids, "123")).count()
```

My first reaction is to use the `MapArray` because checking for membership inside the map is (I assume) more efficient.

On the other hand the built in function `array_contains` executes **scala** code and I assume that whatever scala defined function I call is going to be more efficient than returning the column dict to a python context and checking `k in d.keys()`.

For checking membership in this (multi-value) column, is it best to use the `MapType` or `ArrayType` `pyspark.sql.types`?

**Update**

There is a column method [`pyspark.sql.Column.getItem`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/column.html#Column.getItem) which means I can filter by membership without a python `udf`

Comment: First, `UDF` will slow down the performance. Secondly, I would go with `ArrayType` because an `ID` can have an **arbitrary** values of  count of certain ID's.

Comment: Maps are more performant, in Scala + Spark I used **df.where(df("ids").getItem("123") === true)**, it uses standard Dataframe API and df("ids").getItem("123") returns Column with value of the map or null, I would suspect Pyspark has something similar, so will be at sparks native speed.

Comment: There is @alexeipab thanks

Comment: hey @alexeipab thanks agian for this answer, if you write it out I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maps are more performant, in Scala + Spark I used

```
df.where(df("ids").getItem("123") === true)
```

it uses standard Dataframe API and df("ids").getItem("123") returns **Column** with value of the map or null, it will work at Spark's native speed. Pyspark developers say that Pyspark has that API as well.

Answer (score 0):

On pyspark 3.3+, I prefer the following shortcut:

`df.where(df[“ids”][“123”] == true)`